# Discord slash command "interaction failed"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am following a tutorial for discord slash commands on V13 and there are no errors when I run the but but when I go to do /ping it says interaction failed. I went through the permissions needed on the docs but it looked like I go all the permissions needed to run it which are bot and application commands.

Here is my code for the bot:

```
import DiscordJS, { Intents, Interaction } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready')

    const guildID = '906389171806040114'
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID)
    let commands

    if (guild) {
        commands = guild.commands
    } else {
        commands = client.application?.commands
    }

    commands?.create({
        name: 'pig',
        description: 'Replies with pong',
    })

    commands?.create
})

client.on('interactCreate', async (Interaction) => {
    if (!Interaction.isCommand()) {
        return
    }

    const { commandName, options } = Interaction

    if ( commandName === 'pig') {
        Interaction.reply({
            content: 'pong',
            ephemeral: true,
        })
    }
})



client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You spelled `interactCreate` instead of `interactionCreate`
2. You're using the Interaction class in the callback of that event instead of a new variable called `interaction`
3. You have a random `commands?.create` at the end of the ready event; you should delete that
4. Did you mean to spell `ping` as `pig`? That might cause some problems later on
5. A small suggestion: You could destructure DiscordJS and import Client directly

```js
import { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready')

    const guildID = '906389171806040114'
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID)
    let commands

    if (guild) {
        commands = guild.commands
    } else {
        commands = client.application?.commands
    }

    commands?.create({
        name: 'ping',
        description: 'Replies with pong',
    })
})

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) {
        return
    }

    const { commandName, options } = interaction

    if ( commandName === 'ping') {
        Interaction.reply({
            content: 'pong',
            ephemeral: true,
        })
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks! I went over what you did differnetly and agree. The tutorial I was watching was making more mistakes also and I did not like the way they were doing it. I have know clue why the extra ```commands?.create``` is there. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!